# Unity 2D: Make an image completely black

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to make a copy of an image and make it completely black (silhouette) at runtime. Just changing the color to black doesn't do the trick, for a reason Unity makes some lines transparent:

[image]

Comment: The lines are most probably caused because your image has transparencies there

Comment: @derHugo Yeah, that would make sense.  Thanks for the tip

Answer (score -1):

Its because your image is not completely filled and has gaps where those "lines"  can be seen